# Speed up dictionary merging with soft conjunction logic

Tags: python, dictionary, nlp, search-engine, boolean-logic

I have a look-up table which contains `<word: dictionary>`pairs.
Then, given a word list, 
I can produce a dictionary list using this look-up table.
(Each time, the length of this word list is not fixed). 
Values in these dictionaries represent log probability of some keys.

Here is an example:

Given a word list

`['fruit','animal','plant']`,

we can check out the look-up table and have

`dict_list = [{'apple':-1, 'flower':-2}, {'apple':-3, 'dog':-1}, {'apple':-2, 'flower':-1}]`.

We can see from the list that we have a set of keys: `{'apple', 'flower', 'dog'}`

For each key, I want to give a sum of each value in the dict_list. And if a key is not existed in one dictionary, then we add a small value -10 to the value (you can regard -10 as an very small log probability).

The result dictionary looks like:
`dict_merge = {'apple':-6, 'flower':-13, 'dog':-21}`, 
because `'apple' = (-1) + (-3) + (-2)`, `'flower' = (-2) + (-10) + (-1)`, `'dog' = (-10) + (-1) + (-10)`

Here is my python3 code:

```
dict_list = [{'apple':-1, 'flower':-2}, {'apple':-3, 'dog':-1}, {'apple':-2, 'flower':-1}]

key_list = []
for dic in dict_list:
    key_list.extend(dic.keys())

dict_merge = dict.fromkeys(key_list, 0)
for key in dict_merge:
    for dic in dict_list:
        dict_merge[key] += dic.get(key, -10)
```

**This code works, but if the sizes of some dictionaries in `dict_list` are super large (for example 100,000), then it could take over 200ms, which is not acceptable in practice.**

The main computation is in the `for key in dict_merge` loop, imagine it is a loop of size 100,000.

Is there any speed-up solutions? Thanks! And, thanks for reading~ maybe too long and too annoying...

P.S. 
There are only a few dictionaries in the look-up table have super large size. So there could be some chances here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can understand, `sum(len(d) for d in dict_list)` is much smaller then `len(key_list) * len(dict_list)`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

dict_list = [{'apple':-1, 'flower':-2}, {'apple':-3, 'dog':-1}, {'apple':-2, 'flower':-1}]

default_value = len(dict_list) * (-10)
dict_merge = defaultdict(lambda: default_value)
for d in dict_list:
    for key, value in d.items():
        dict_merge[key] += value + 10
```

Comment: Thats a really good answer - can you explain more how this differs from the original algorithm and why it ultimately will produce the same result

Comment: Thanks! Yes, this is faster. But since `len(dict_list)` is always less than three and we still have to scan over the keys_number in the end, it does not speed up that much.

Comment: @DongxuZhang I've updated the answer, now we don't need to iterate over keys twice.

Comment: @f1u77y Cool! Brilliant!